# Using easy_thumbnails_ffmpeg

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, thumbnails, easy-thumbnails

I want to use the easy_thumbnails_ffmpeg library to get Thumbnails for videos in Python, however, I get a weird error saying that the file was not found. I have been looking for examples of how to use the library, but no luck and no documentation either. Any idea ? thank you

Log:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\easy_thumbnails_ffmpeg-0.1.1-py2.7.egg\easy_thumbnails_ffmpeg\source_generators.py", line 24, in ffmpeg_frame
    ], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate(source.read())[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Specified file not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `file not found` error likely means that the library is trying to call ffmpeg, but the binary does not work/isn't found. Inspecting the [source of `easy_thumbnails_ffmpeg`](https://github.com/pluma/easy-thumbnails-ffmpeg/blob/master/easy_thumbnails_ffmpeg/source_generators.py), you can see it tries to call `ffmpeg` on the command line. Is ffmpeg on your PATH, such that you can call it in the same manner from a command prompt?

I.e., if you opened a command prompt, see if executing `ffmpeg` works for you. If it doesn't, add the binary to your PATH.

Comment: This solved the problem, any idea about what should be passed to source_generators.ffmpeg_frame as a source for the video ? path, open('path') ? Thank you

Comment: From inspecting the source code, it looks like the `source` param takes in a file handler, ie `open(path)`, because on line 24 the lib calls `source.read()`